# Can service fabric autoscaling scale out nodes as well?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Based on this 
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-autoscaling), auto scaling instances or partitions are provided from service fabric.

However, what's confusing is if this can also provide auto-scaling in/out of the nodes(VMs / actual physical environment), which seems not mentioned explicitly.

Comment: i **think** vmss autoscaling can do that, not service fabric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can auto scale the cluster as well, assuming that you are running in Azure. This will be done based on performance counter data. It works by defining rules on the VM scaleset.

Note that in order to automatically scale down gracefully, it's recommended you use the durability level Gold or Silver, otherwise you'll be responsible to drain the node before it's taken out of the cluster.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview).

Comment: Maybe I just assumed but does the autoscale of instances / partitions also apply to Actor services?

Comment: No, partiton scaling works on named partitions only, Actor services use int64 range partitons. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform  Instance scaling works for stateless services.

Comment: Funny enough I saw my old comment in that link and based on the thread discussion auto-scaling of actors seems not possible. Is that still true?

Comment: I think so, until the SF team releases functionality repartition service data on the fly.